# Check for zero duration with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've implemented a function which get a [ISO 8601 duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) string and calculates a sequence for a day.

The function hangs for invalid duration strings. These strings are interpreted as zero duration and therefore the function builds an infinite sequence `["00:00","00:00",...]`.

```
timeSeq("PT12H")
// ["00:00", "12:00"]

timeSeq(undefined)
// hangs ....
```

Zero duration maps to `P0D` via `duration.toISOString()`. How should I check for zero duration within my function?

```
const timeSeq = (durationString, format = "HH:mm") => {
  const duration = moment.duration(durationString);
  // function should return [] for zero duration
  // ???
  const current = moment().startOf("day");
  const end = current.clone().add(1, "day").startOf("day");
  const sequence = [];
  while (current < end) {
    sequence.push(current.format(format));
    current.add(duration);
  }
  return sequence;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get duration value using [`as`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/as/) function, you can use [`asMilliseconds()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/milliseconds/) or `as('milliseconds')` (or similar getters).

Moreover you can check is an object is a duration using [`moment.isDuration(obj)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/is-a-duration/).

You can use somenthing like this:

```js
function isZeroDuration(dur){
  if( !moment.isDuration(dur) ){
    return true;
  }
  return dur.as('milliseconds') === 0;
}

[null, undefined, 'P0D', 'hello', 'P1D'].forEach((durationString) => {
  const duration = moment.duration(durationString);
  console.log(durationString, isZeroDuration(duration) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Since my function above doesn't work correctly with negative durations, I adapted your solution to `return dur.as('milliseconds') <= 0;`.

Comment: You are right, the provided sample is made for question title (_Check for zero duration with momentjs_), looking deeper at the question `<=` fits better with your needs.